# How do I export all Controlling Field Industries & the dependent Sub-Industries?

Tags: account, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

Is it possible for me to extract a list of each industry and then be able to see each sub-industry (dependent field) ?

I know I can get printable views of both fields but I want to be able to show in Excel which industry has which specific sub-industry.

Comment: you want the metadata setup? or the actual values used in data records?

Comment: Just the metadata set up to see the exact structure we currently have options for - it's for a project at work to re-define / reduce the amount of industries & sub that we currently have available

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension [Salesforce Dependent Picklist Matrix Export](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-dependent-pick/fpieolagnlkejcpejlbjgbdpaglffacj) to download the parent and child matrix field to csv. upu can then open it in excel and filter to see the child values for a particular parent value. A demo is also available in the extension.